# Swift returning a let value

Tags: swift

So all I want to do is be able to return a var / let value back to the view which is in SwiftUI.

I can currently do this for JSON data. but the following won't be JSON. It will just be a string passed and returned.

nowplaying.swift

```
let nowplaying: String

class Api {
    func nowPlaying(completion: @escaping ([nowplaying]) -> ()) {
          
                   let nowplaying = "string"
                   DispatchQueue.main.async{
                       // The array is stored under station now
                       completion(nowplaying)
                   }
                   
    
           .resume()
           }
}
```

podcastView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct Podcasts: View {
    
     let post: Program
    
    @State var nowplaying: [nowplaying] = []
    
    var body: some View {
      
     
            ZStack {
                  Color.blue
               //   Text(post.url)
                  Text(nowplaying)
               
            }
            .onAppear(
            //RUN CODE TO Fetch podcast episodes.
                Api().nowPlaying { (nowplaying) in
                               self.nowplaying = nowplaying
                }
            )
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(post.title), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(false)
           
      
        
        
    
    }
        
}
```

Now I am going to guess that the reason this is not working is due to this part

```
completion: @escaping ([nowplaying])
```

is not a JSON returned string. So question is if NOT returning a JSON string but rather a text String how do I do it?

Also how do you send data to this func

for example in Node I would have

```
 func nowPlaying(incomingData, completion: @escaping ([nowplaying]) -> ()) {

                  print(incomingData)

                   let nowplaying = "string"
                   DispatchQueue.main.async{
                       // The array is stored under station now
                       completion(nowplaying)
                   }


           .resume()
           }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your completion need to define the type to take in parameter, not a variable.

```swift
func nowPlaying(completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
    // ...
}
```

You also needs to change your view

```swift
@State var nowplaying: String = ""
```

(It should not be an Array as your are using it in a `Text` view).

Also the first `let nowplaying: String` in `nowplaying.swift` is useless. You should remove that.

**Edit**

Didn't saw that at first but:

`.resume()` in `nowPlaying(completion:)` function has nothing to do here. Just remove it.

In your `Podcasts` view, `onAppear` as the wrong syntax. It is actually expecting a closure, so you should use `{ }` instead of `( )`:

```swift
.onAppear {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks - Just getting the following with my view tho:

Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '(() -> Void)?'

Comment: Thank you that worked - is their away to send data to only that function and on when sending a request to it - I need to pass data to it that's all.  func nowPlaying(Station...

and then I can send an optional field like Station name to it?

Comment: You should take a look at the Swift documentation for all syntax related stuff (function, closures, etc..).